# Does the Bluelight Filter for Eye Care app really work?

Tags: applications

Does the [Bluelight Filter for Eye Care](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.hardyinfinity.bluelightfilter.free) app really work? Can you tell me why it is helpful to protect eyes?

Comment: Rephrased question so it's clearer and doesn't get closed.

Comment: This question is off-topic since it's not specifically Android related. The same question can be asked to other light-emitting device, such as other smartphones, and PC monitors. The second part of the question is also off-topic and more suitable on [biology.se] or [health.se]. And lastly, as of current writing, it invites opinion based answer. This probably can be salvaged by changing the question to ask for fact based, like "Is it possible to filter bluelight using app on Android?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These apps really work. There are lot of apps that I have used to reduce eye strains such as [lux auto brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux&hl=en), [darker pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mlhg.screenfilterpro&hl=en), [juice defender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender&hl=en)'s brightness settings,  etc.

Comment: To add to @user52165's answer, changing color of the screen to orange or blue(ish) is easier on the eyes. Hence, it reduces eye strain, especially when you're trying to read the screen late at night (and you're very sleepy).

Comment: The app purports to reduce the blue light emitted by your device, so the question is really whether that is even possible on Android.  Since this answer conflates a bunch of apps that do different things, I doubt it really addresses the issue of blue light.  The other answer says that it is not possible, but it looks suspicious.  I'm still not sure of the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you that no app can really filter the blue light emitted from your digital screen. This kind of app does reduce our eye strain because it helps to change the contrast, adjust the brightness, and add some shades. Want to know whether the eye care app filters blue light effectively, you should use a spectrometer.

In this video, you can see clearly how blue light has been filtered by T’amie blue-light protection glasses with the use of a spectrometer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmUebEu3GzE&noredirect=1

In fact, most of us computer workers pay more attention to eye care from blue light and eye strain. But we should make the right choice to protect our eyes.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the link in question. It feels like promotion (which is allowed on this site, but only if it is relevant *and* you give full disclosure).

Comment: This answer makes a claim but does not offer anything to back it up. The video does not address apps. "No app can really filter the blue light emitted from your digital screen"? Prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Bluelight filter apps do help to reduce blue light.

Assume you have a fully blue screen on your mobile. Each pixel would obviously be emitting blue light. The effect of blue light is not the effect of the waves unlike UV rays that damage cells. Its effect on human beings arise from the fact that our biological processes associated with sleep is linked by nature to an absence of blue colored objects in nature at night. Now, let us place a red opaque screen on top of the blue screen described earlier. Obviously, the eye now sees a red screen and it does not trigger any sleep hormones. A blue light filter app uses this phenomenon by using a semi-transparent non-bluish overlay that increases the reddishness and/or greenishness of the screen.

We have developed an app to reduce the bluishness of the screen. It has no ads, over 400 good reviews, and small file size (~86kb). You can try it out or just read through the reviews to understand how it is helping users.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panagola.app.bluef

Affiliation: Developer, Non-profit

Answer (score 0):

Some useful apps can truly block blue light and offer eye protection. And I also approve the upstairs' point: blue light blocking percentage differs due to the different apps and products. Generally speaking, I enjoy the F.lux on my Android phone very much.

Besides, a blue light protective eyewear is great for eye protection, too.